# Remove zeros from middle of string

Tags: vba, excel-formula

I have a list of serial numbers with a prefix, and then a few numbers. All serial numbers are 8 characters, so depending on the prefix and amount of zeros, different amounts of leading zeros are added between the prefix and numbers. (ex. ALT00001, CAT00564, AAR19470, M0000003, MISC7859, MISC0025)
How can I remove all leading zeros from the Serial Numbers, but keep any zeros that are part of the actual number?

I would love to create a macro that does this, as I would have to run this code on multiple workbooks countless times a day.

Comment: Tell us what is the result you expected.

Comment: ALT1, CAT564, AAR19470, M3, MISC7859, MISC25

Comment: will the prefix contains number such as A4BC0001?

Comment: @TerryW No, the prefix will never contain a number

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,3) & --RIGHT(A1,5)
```

and copy downwards.

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

Based on the updated examples, we must find the position of the **first numeral** in the string and parse based on that.

In **C1** enter:

```
=MIN(FIND({"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"},UPPER(A1)&"0123456789"))
```

and copy downwards. *(this give the position of the first numeral)*

Now in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,C1-1) & --RIGHT(A1,8-C1+1)
```

or:

```
=LEFT(A1,C1-1) & --RIGHT(A1,9-C1)
```

*(if you don't want the "helper" column, combine the formulas)*

**EDIT#2:**

Here is some code:

```
Sub Deb()
    Dim Kolumn As String, rng As Range, cell As Range, s As String, L As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Kolumn = "A"
    Set rng = Intersect(Columns(Kolumn).EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Offset(1, 0).Cells

    For Each cell In rng
        s = cell.Value
        If s = "" Then Exit Sub
        L = Len(s)
        For i = 1 To L
            If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) Then
                GoTo Process
            End If
        Next i
        MsgBox "bad data " & s
        Exit Sub
Process:
        cell.Value = Left(s, i + -1) & CLng(Mid(s, i))
    Next cell

End Sub
```

**EDIT#3:**

Macros are very easy to **install** and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To **use** the macro from the Excel window:

1. Select the worksheet you want the macro to run on
2. ALT-F8
3. Select the macro
4. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#4:**

This code check for errors:

```
Sub Deb_2()
    Dim Kolumn As String, rng As Range, cell As Range, s As String, L As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Kolumn = "A"
    Set rng = Intersect(Columns(Kolumn).EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange).Offset(1, 0).Cells

    For Each cell In rng
        s = cell.Value
        If s = "" Then Exit Sub
        L = Len(s)
        For i = 1 To L
            If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i, 1)) Then
                GoTo Process
            End If
        Next i
        MsgBox "bad data " & s
        Exit Sub
Process:
        If IsNumeric(Mid(s, i)) Then
            cell.Value = Left(s, i + -1) & CLng(Mid(s, i))
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197073/discussion-on-answer-by-garys-student-remove-zeros-from-middle-of-string).

Answer (score 0):

I have two approaches, one is using **excel array formula** to find the numerical value in the text string, and the other is using **excel power query** to transform the data in 4 simple steps.

> Approach 1 - Array Formula

The following formula will firstly convert the text string to array, eg. `ALT00001` will become `{"A";"L";"T";"0";"0";"0";"0";"1"}`, then examine each character in the array if it is a numerical value like this `{FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE}`, and lastly sum up all the TRUE results. This will give you the total number of numerical values in the text string.

```
{=SUM(--ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)))}
```

Please note this is an **array formula** so you need to press **CSE** (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) upon finishing editing the formula.

[image: Approach 1]

In my workings, I entered the array formula in Cell B1, then in Cell C1 I entered the following formula to get the result.

```
=LEFT(A1,8-B1)&--RIGHT(A1,B1)
```

You can combine these two formulas but it will look awkwardly long and not so easy to interpret by others. If you do combine, you need to press **CSE** to make it work as it incorporates an array.

> Approach 2 - Power Query

Although @Deb did not ask for a solution using Power Query (PQ), I still want to share an alternative way of solving the issue efficiently, given that the above formula-based solution is not so straight forward and somehow complicated.

PQ is able to transform data from multiple worksheets and have ample built-in functions that is quite user friendly. Please note you need to have **Excel 2010 or later versions** to be able to use PQ.

So here are the steps using PQ:

1) Load the data range to PQ Editor, one way of doing that is to highlight the data range and use **From Table** in the **Data** tab as shown below:

[image: From Table]

2) Once loaded, the PQ Editor will be opened in a new window. The next step is to separate the value into Text string and Numerical string. A quick way of doing that is to use the **Split Column (By Non-digit to Digit)** in the **Transform** tab of the PQ Editor as shown below.

[image: Split Column]

3) Now we have the text in the first column and the number in the second column. Next step is to clear the "**0**" in front of the values in the number column. One way of doing that is to change the **Data Type** from `Text` to `Whole Number`, and then change it back to `Text` (I will explain why you need to change it back to Text in the next step).

[image: Change Type]

4) Next step is to combine the two columns to get the desired result. One way of doing that is to **add a custom column** and use `&` to combine the values from the two columns as shown below.

```
=[Column1.1]&[Column1.2] the way of using & is same as in an excel formula
```

[image: Add Custom Column]

As mentioned in my last step, we need to change the number value back to `text`, the reason is that PQ Editor does not allow combining a text value with a numerical value, it will lead to the following error.

[image: Error]

5) The last step will vary depends on your preference. What I did is to **remove other columns** and **load** the Result column to the current worksheet where your original data sits.

[image: Close and Load]

Unfortunately PQ could not over write source data. However in my opinion it is better to keep your source data somewhere safe without being overwritten, and export your edited/transformed data to a new place and work on it instead.

Here are the codes behind the scene but all steps are performed using the built-in functions which you can google the know-how of each of them easily.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Character Transition",{{"Column1.2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type1",{{"Column1.2", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type2", "Result", each [Column1.1]&[Column1.2]),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Result"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

Cheers :)